# What does this lean key prompt mean?

Tags: battlefield-4

While playing the game, every once in a while I get this key prompt for leaning. It looks like I should press the right mouse button, but that only goes into aim-down-sights -mode. What does it mean and what does it do?

[image: /||\LEAN LEFT]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BF4 uses a "smart lean" system.  The beta is a bit buggy with it, but the premise is that when that pops up, you are by a corner and holding the ADS button will cause you to lean around that corner, exposing less of yourself to the enemy.  The best way to see it is to stand at the corner of a wall and play with it.  It takes some getting used to but once you do, it will feel smooth.

Comment: so it is a beta issue that it appears in middle of open areas (as seen in the screenshot)

Comment: Yep.  I'll see it pop up a couple seconds after I was at a corner sometimes.  It's probably some internal lag.

Comment: @3ventic Yep, I get the same too, you probably passed a corner where it was possible, and it kinda showed afterwards :p

Comment: "bit buggy" being "I've never got it to work at all"

Comment: Make sure you never attempt to throw a grenade when leaning.  You will pull the pin, step back under cover, and promptly throw the grenade at your feet.